# Java concurrency handling

Tags: java, concurrency

For concurrency handling i have written and executor class :

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
                    Future<List<Content>> submit = service.submit(new PushClass(pushlist, content));
                    List<Content> resu = submit.get();
```

and Below is the push class that implements the Callable interface :

```
 public class PushClass implements Callable<List<Content>> {

List<Content> ls;
String content;

public PushClass(List<Content> ls, String content) {
    this.ls = ls;
    this.content = content;
}

private synchronized String push(String msisdn, String content, String Cli) {

       // hitting the push url
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;

}

@Override
public List<Content> call() throws Exception {

    for (Content c : ls) {
        c.setResponse(push(c.getMsisdn(), content, c.getCli()));
    }
    return ls;
}
```

Upto what limit can i increase the thread to as to prevent any queuing in the server or can i make the pool dynamic ? Sometimes tomcat is showing error as , "The Other thread are in process" , can i dynamically scale it.

Comment: You should try Apache DBCP for connection pooling : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: Consider caching database entries and commit them as a batch rather then having 6000 inserts per second.

Comment: You could synchronize a method to manage a List/Queue, then push to the server when your threshold is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes connection pooling will help manage db resources better, just open connection once and return it back to pool, instead of closing, about the pool size I leave it upto you (Even one may suffice)
2. The best thing you can do to improve performance is *[batchUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm)* i.e. commit the transaction to db only after some 500-1000 records to get rid of the db overhead
3. You can bring in multiple threads to take the incoming load, multi-threading should be simple in your case since the operation to be done is atomic in nature (assuming you only have inserts), please explore java [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for this. [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), you can select no. of threads based on testing, start with 10.

Comment: From the link: 'For both standard update batching and Oracle update batching, Oracle recommends you to keep the batch sizes in the general range of 50 to 100. This is because though the drivers support larger batches, they in turn result in a large memory footprint with no corresponding increase in performance. Very large batches usually result in a decline in performance compared to smaller batches.'

Comment: @JohnManko: Thanks for pointing it out, but then maybe they did not consider 6K requests per second scenario, from my experience only way to be sure is to test and benchmark, nothing else works.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can add a comment, if you downvote, I want to learn too, do not deprive me of that opportunity :)